# Error while trying Pandas series split using a Dictionary that has the Split info

Tags: python, pandas, split

**Pandas series split using a Dictionary that has the Split info**

I have the below data frame

```
columns = ['ID','DESIGN_APPROVER','PLAN APPROVER','FINAL_APPROVER']
data = [['ID_001','Sheldon,US','Leonard,Canada', 'Howard,Japan'],
        ['ID_002','Joel,UK','Tommy,Paris', 'Angelo,Ireland']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data , columns=columns)
df
```

**Data frame looks like**

```
        ID      DESIGN_APPROVER PLAN APPROVER   FINAL_APPROVER
0   ID_001  Sheldon,US      Leonard,Canada  Howard,Japan
1   ID_002  Joel,UK         Tommy,Paris     Angelo,Ireland
```

**Also I have a dict which specifies how each of the column has to be splitted**

```
key_list = list(set(df.columns)-{'ID'})
value_list = [['{}_NAME'.format(i),'{}_LOCATION'.format(i)] for i in key_list]
dict(zip(key_list, value_list))
split_dict
```

**split_dict**

```
{'PLAN APPROVER': ['PLAN APPROVER_NAME', 'PLAN APPROVER_LOCATION'],
 'FINAL_APPROVER': ['FINAL_APPROVER_NAME', 'FINAL_APPROVER_LOCATION'],
 'DESIGN_APPROVER': ['DESIGN_APPROVER_NAME','DESIGN_APPROVER_LOCATION']}
```

**My Requirement**: How to iterate through the dictionary to split the key column into value columns based on ',' delimiter. I tried the below code

```
    for k,v in split_dict:
        df[v] = df[k].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

but getting

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple loop and set a max number of split that matches the length of the list (-1):

```
out = []
for k,v in split_dict.items():
    # for each key, pop (=remove and returns) the column
    # use it as input to str.split to split in n chunks on comma
    # the the maximum number of split to x-1 where x is the number
    # of items in the list
    df[v] = df.pop(k).str.split(',', n=len(v)-1)
```

output:

```
       ID PLAN APPROVER_NAME PLAN APPROVER_LOCATION FINAL_APPROVER_NAME FINAL_APPROVER_LOCATION DESIGN_APPROVER_NAME DESIGN_APPROVER_LOCATION
0  ID_001            Leonard                  Tommy              Howard                  Angelo              Sheldon                     Joel
1  ID_002             Canada                  Paris               Japan                 Ireland                   US                       UK
```

*NB. if you want to keep the original column, use slicing instead of `pop`.:*

```
out = []
for k,v in split_dict.items():
    df[v] = df[k].str.split(',', n=len(v)-1)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code inside the for loop

Comment: I added comments, let me know if something specific is unclear

Comment: can you please explain why

 `df[v] = df[k].str.split(',', n=len(v)-1)`  runs successfully but

 `df[v] = df[k].str.split(',', expand=True)` throws error

but when I don't use dict and do a flat coding it runs successfully with expand = True

 `df[['PLAN APPROVER_NAME', 'PLAN APPROVER_LOCATION']] = df['PLAN APPROVER'].str.split(',',expand=True)`

Comment: The issue was not the `expand=True` but likely the fact that some of your fields have more than 1 comma, thus my use of `n` parameter to set the max number of splits

Comment: The issue is the way you are iterating the dict. The way you are doing it only returns one value, i.e., key. Therefore, the _ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)__ error. Change it to `for k, v in split_dict.items()`. Otherwise, your code is fine. The `n=len(v)-1` thingy is a good safety measure if there are unequal numbers of values in your list.